# Has the loan of securities from a retail investor to a well-established US broker ever resulted in a financial loss to the retail investor?

Tags: nonexpert, united-states

Retail investors may opt to loan some of the shares to their brokers:

[image]

In theory, one of the risks is that the broker and the collateral may have some issue, leaving the retail investor with a financial loss.

In practice, has the loan of securities from a retail investor to a well-established US broker ever resulted in a financial loss to the retail investor?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I'm still interested in this question, in case anyone has an answer.